# cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::filesystem::path' to 'const cv::String &' (std::string)

Tags: c++

**I have the following code:**

```
int upsample(DnnSuperResImpl model,
                      std::filesystem::path f,
                      std::filesystem::path s) {
    Mat img = cv::imread(f); //Read image
    Mat img;
    sr.upsample(img, img_new)
    cv::imwrite(s/ f.filename(), img); //Save upscaled image
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know why the f and s are not allowed to be written without adding .string() ?

Comment: try `(save_dir / file_path.filename()).string()`